# SQL code in python - double indexing pivot table counts

Tags: python, sql

I created my own DB and added my csv data into it successfully via Python. Queries therefore work, but I use python to do the queries. Package sqlite3. In short, the table is: ID of user, Type of action performed, ID of object that action was performed on.

df1 and df2 are the DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3    
connection = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
c = connection.cursor()
df1.to_sql('tab1', con = connection, if_exists = 'replace', chunksize = 1000)
df2.to_sql('tab2', con = connection, if_exists = 'replace', chunksize = 1000)
```

In this SQL command, I need to select the columns, join one table and select only data from certain time. I hope it's okay I include it there for completeness but won't include all columns in example table as they're only for the filtering. **Note that the subquery without the pivot works**.

```
sql_command = """
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT tab1.action,
        tab1.iduser,
        tab2.idobject
FROM tab1, 
     tab2
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.objectid = tab2.objectid
      WHERE tab2.Datetime BETWEEN '2020-01-29' AND '2020-02-04'
) AS source 
PIVOT( 
      COUNT(tab1.iduser)
      FOR tab1.action IN (
          [a],
          [b],
          [c])
      ) AS pivot_table;"""

# execute query
c.execute(sql_command)
```

This is the table I get from the subquery basically:

```
iduser      action     idobject
--------------------------------------
1              a         Obj1
1              b         Obj2
1              c         Obj3
1              a         Obj2
2              a         Obj1
2              c         Obj2
2              a         Obj2
2              b         Obj1
3              a         Obj1
3              c         Obj3
```

Now I want to create such table, i.e. count the number of types of actions performed on each object.

```
action   idobject      Count
----------------------------------------------------------------------
a           Obj1          3
            Obj2          2
            Obj3          0
b           Obj1          1
            Obj2          1
            Obj3          0
c           Obj1          0
            Obj2          1
            Obj3          2
```

If i run the code above with the PIVOT table, I get the error "Error: Incorrect syntax near "PIVOT"".

Comment: the Pivot function is not in the Language definitions for SQLite as per https://sqlite.org/lang.html

Comment: No two SQL dialects (outside of the ANSI SQL standard) are alike. `PIVOT` is not supported in SQLite. However, pandas has many pivot functionality. See this canonical `pandas` post [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/1422451)

Comment: Actually you appear to only need `groupby` aggregation: `df.groupby(['action', 'idobject'])['iduser'].count()`